# How do I use SAPUI5 SDK?

Tags: sapui5

I am four months incumbent to SAPUI5. I know the basics of SAPUI5 and am able to create application from scratch. However , this is true only for the controls that I am familiar with(I refer google/SAPUI5 SDK). Lately, I am realizing if it is brand new control for me, I have to spend a lot of time using SAPUI5 SDK going after the API reference, documentation and samples.

My question is could you please let me know how do I use SDK effectively ? For example, I need to know the method when a cell is clicked in sap.m.Table or an event for selection. How do I use documentation, API reference for it ?

Kindly help!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are doing is correct, API reference has everything you need.

I can tell you the tricks I did while working on SAPUI5:

1. Every time you visit a reference about a particular control, watch out from where it has been inherited. This gives an edge, most control will have basic handlers at the parent control which can be reused in child controls. Example [sap.ui.core.Element](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element), this is like Grandfather of many controls. Spend time to understand this kind of controls.
2. Use browser console as your playground, create a particular object you are playing with, then use `.`and see what are the methods which are exposed.
3. Aggregations tell you about what is the kind of content a control can take in.

There is no other magic to this. Trust me, over a period of time, you will be very much faster in figuring out what fits.

~Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When I work with new controls it helped me to take a look at the control samples first and its coding. This gives me a good quick overview.

Then I take a closer look at the API to that control to find out more about the properties, aggregations and events.

Sometimes I build a quick and simple example app for a certain control. This helps me to find out how the control is supposed to work.

As already mentioned, there is no way that works for everyone and it'll take some time.

You'll find your best way of working with it.